# How can I center a image when it is displayed in both 3.5 inch and 4 inch iphone screen?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimage

[image]

I want the image in yellow square be displayed when the app is running 3.5 inch screen. However, now it just simply display the upper part of the image (the area in red square). So, how can I make the image always be centered.

I use photoshop to draw the effect that I want. I want the image to be like this:

In 4 inch screen:

[image]

In 3.5 inch screen:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Whatever, don't you think this will do your needs

```
[self.imgView setCenter:self.view.center];
```

OR

```
[self.imgView setCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2, self.view.frame.size.height / 2)]
```

`self.view.center` gives you the center of visible portion of your current view.

Answer (score 1):

Simply adjust the Autosizing of the imageView .

Answer (score 1):

in `xib` file select image then:

- Editor
- Align
- Horizontal Center in container

Again select image

- Editor
- Align
- Vertical Center in container

thats it.

Answer (score 0):

set frame of `UIImageView`

```
myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, self.view.frame.size.width - (x*2), self.view.frame.size.height - (y*2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the imageview in the Storyboard , then add following two constraints. You can add constraint by clicking small icons just below your view. In this case you will find following option by clicking 1st icon of the group of 4 icons.

1. Horizontal center in container - 0
2. Vertical center in container -0

Make sure your imageview is selected when adding those constraints.

Answer (score 0):

set constraint for your imageview both top and bottom

[image]

check your 3.5 and 4 inch screen using bottom of first icon

3.5 screen

[image]

4 inch screen

[image]